# MultiDPIBitmapSource in BitmapFill

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

I'm trying to select background image depending on the dpi, but even I can write the following code it do not work.

```
<s:Rect id="backgroundRect" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
<s:fill>
    <s:BitmapFill id="myBack" fillMode="scale">
       <s:source>
          <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource
                     source160dpi="@Embed('assets/ldpi/BackGround.png')"
                     source240dpi="@Embed('assets/mdpi/BackGround.png')"
             source320dpi="@Embed('assets/hdpi/BackGround.png')"/>
        </s:source>
     </s:BitmapFill>
</s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Using Flash Builder 4.6 mobile application.

Thanks for any help.

Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to turn off applicationDPI="160"